# Download a .csv file Java6

Tags: java, java-6

I'm trying to download a file from a server.

I have this method but when I open the downloaded File, it is in ByteCode, and it's not readable.

```
            File file = new File(request.getPath());
            response.setContentType("text/csv;charset=utf-8");
            response.setHeader("Content-Disposition","attachment; filename="+file.getName());
            response.setHeader("filename",file.getName());
            OutputStream resOs= response.getOutputStream();
            OutputStream buffOs= new BufferedOutputStream(resOs);
            OutputStreamWriter outputwriter = new OutputStreamWriter(buffOs);

            FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(file);  //read the file
            try {
                int c;
                while ((c = inputStream.read()) != -1) {
                    outputwriter.write(c);
                }
            } finally {
                inputStream.close();
                outputwriter.flush();
                outputwriter.close();
            }
        };
```

where is the problem?

Comment: From the javadoc _"FileInputStream is meant for reading streams of raw bytes such as image data. For reading streams of characters, consider using FileReader."_

Comment: Is there a reason you’re using Java 6, when the current version of Java is 12?

Answer (score 2):

Since your approach writes byte data, Set content type to application/octet-stream,

```
            response.setContentType("application/octet-stream");
```

Comment: When you already recognize that this is about byte data, you should also remove the `OutputStreamWriter` from the solution, as it obviously is the wrong tool to copy byte data. Even better, instead of doing a loop copying the content byte for byte, drop the `BufferedOutputStream` as well and do `inputStream.getChannel().transferTo(0, file.length(), Channels.newChannel(resOs));`, to copy the data in one go.

Comment: The content of the file is relevant to determine the content type for the response. It does not matter if the content was read using a stream or a reader. It also does not matter if you wrote to the servlet response using `getOutputStream` or `getWriter`. Thus, the downvote.

Answer (score 1):

You use an input stream to read single bytes from your input file. It is a text file, but if you don't care about the text content, it is OK to read it using a stream.

Next, you create a BufferedWriter and start writing the byte (8bit) you read from your stream as chars into your writer. This is an issue, IMHO.

As soon as you have a multibyte-characters in your input file, you are starting to do strange things.

It's OK to read your text file using a stream, but then you should also write the output using a stream. Do not mix reader/writer and streams.

It's also OK to set content type as text/csv, even if you read the file using a stream, provided the file is a text file of course.

Comment: Mixing `InputStream` and `Writer` may cause problems for every encoding, except ASCII and ISO-LATIN-1, not just multi-byte encodings.

Comment: @Holger Why? For all single-byte encodings, a byte matches a character. So reading/writing one char/byte should not make a difference. Internally, both of them are represented with an int in the range -[1, 255]. Where do you see an issue here?

Comment: No, a byte does not match a character. Only for those 8 bit encodings being based on ASCII, the bytes in the value range 0-127 will match with the unicode character. But ISO-LATIN-1 is the only 8 bit encoding, for which the byte values in the 128-255 range match the character codepoints of the same value. When you pass the value to the `write` method of a `Writer`, it will be interpreted as codepoint according to the Unicode standard and encoded according to the writer’s charset.